# Sequelize truncate method dropping table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to delete the content of one table using sequelize, I have created a convenient model for the table and I'm using this code:

```
Table.truncate({transaction: t})
```

Now I'm getting the error **DROP command denied to user**. Why is he trying to drop the table when i want only delete the content of the table?

Is there a way to simply delete the rows without dropping the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.sync`

```
Table.sync({force : true}); // this will clear all the entries in your table.
```

**OR**

This is a convenient method for `Model.destroy({ truncate: true })` as per the **[DOC](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-truncate)**